# getting authToken of a Google Account in Android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, cloud-hosting

I am trying to model an app based on http://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/

```
authBundle = am.getAuthToken(account, APPENGINE_SERVICE_NAME,
                        needAuthAction == NEED_AUTH_NOTIFICATION, null, null).getResult();


authToken = authBundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
```

authToken is returned null in this case.

What can be possible causes for this?

Answer (score 1):

Does the account already exist on the device? From the Class Overview section of the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) javadoc:

> **Important:** If the application is using
>   a previously remembered account
>   selection, it must make sure the
>   account is still in the list of
>   accounts returned by
>   getAccountsByType(String). Requesting
>   an auth token for an account no longer
>   on the device results in an undefined
>   failure.

Comment: For now, I am assuming that a user's account already exists. But in the future, if it does not exist, a user will provide it. I already retrieved the auth key from AccountManager (Account[] accts = mgr.getAccountsByType("com.google");) for a google account. But now the question is about a way to retrieve google calendar names so that a user can add/edit/delete events.